# Can we search inside xib files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, xib

I once had a bug where the xib still have a reference to a certain variable.

The reason why the bug is so tough to find is if I search for that variable it doesn't show at all.

Say I want to know which xib still have a reference iboutlet to certain pictures. How do I do so?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to open them as XMLs in some editor and search them there.

Comment: what about if you have tons of xib?

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that there are editors that search the entire project for specific strings (Textmate for example) and also support file filtering.

Comment: Yes it's for mac. You can grab a copy from their Github repo here: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. XIBs are human readable. Simply search for the name of an image using your text editor or [`grep` the image name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963378/text-search-though-all-xib-files-in-xcode?rq=1).

During the build process, they are typically converted to another, smaller representation (known as "flattening"). So you want to look specifically at the XIBs you edit, rather than the ones converted and copied to the app bundle's contents.

Comment: Say I have 20 xibs and I want to know which one contain variable ISSomeVariableName?

Comment: @JimThio yeah, you can just open them or their parent directory in something like TextWrangler (or another text editor which will interpret it as just a text file), then perform a find/search for `ISSomeVariableName` and the results will be returned to you in the search results. You could also use `grep` in this case. Perhaps not every editor does, but TextWrangler and TextMate will both do it.

Comment: @JimThio and to grep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963378/text-search-though-all-xib-files-in-xcode?rq=1